# gauge R&R of time varying data: how to discriminate between equipment variation and actual signal variation?

Tags: statistics, measurement, heart-rate

I am trying to evaluate a measurement system suitability for some physiological parameters say heart rate. If I collect say 30 measurements of my heart rate, the standard deviation of the population will include equipment standard deviation and subject hear rate standard deviation. The latter is not noise, hence I would like to quantify only the equipment measurement variation, any ideas?

that's a classic problem for qualifying medical devices I imagine, but could not find anything clear on this unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

If you measure only your heart rate, you can only provide measures of the "population" of your own heart rate. You should not take a sample from one individual as indicative of the population of all persons and their heart rates.

I'm not sure you can understand the variation of heart rates generated from a single device when measured on a non-standardized heart rate. If you had a standardized heart rate and number of different devices, then you could comment on agreement if the heart rates are measured under the same condition.